# @ngxs/form-plugin: handling single field change

Tags: angular, ngxs

Form plugin provides `UpdateFormValue` action that allows to handle changes in form fields. However it's dispatched for every field change of the form. So if I have multiple fields in a form (e.g. email and name) and I want to do something on email change but ignore name change I have to subscribe to `valueChanges` observable in the component like this:

```js
...
this.myForm.controls.email.valueChanges.subscribe(emailValue => {
    /* dispatch my special action Actions.UserChangedEmail or something */
}
```

Is this the correct approach or is it possible to handle it in a state with a method that uses `@Action(UpdateFormValue)` or seomthing like that?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
 this.myForm.get('email').valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
    this.myForm.get('email').setValue(value, { onlySelf: true, emitEvent: false, emitModelToViewChange: true });
}, error => { }, () => { });
```

Comment: I don't think you understood the question. I have a state managed by NGXS and its form plugin. I want to react to a single field change (ignoring changes of other field value) inside the NGXS state class, just like I do with other actions I dispatch for that state.